# Why my syntax is error? (TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable)

Tags: tuples, typeerror

My syntax is like this

```
print ("Hello!")
print ("Ayah berkata, \"Semangat\"")
print ("Ayah berkata,", end=" ")
print ("\"Semangat\"")
```

and my output is like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-122075a697db> in <module>()
----> 1 print ("Hello!")
      2 print ("Ayah berkata, \"Semangat\"")
      3 print ("Ayah berkata,", end=" ")
      4 print ("\"Semangat\"")

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I'm code at google colab

Comment: Presumably you've shadowed the built-in print function with a tuple.

Answer (score -1):

You have created a variable named "print" which is a tuple. You have to remove or rename the variable "print".

```py
>>> print = ("test", "test") # <- somewhere there might be a linge likethis one
>>> print ("Anything")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```